# Give SMPP connection via JSMPP

Tags: java, smpp, jsmpp

I have SMPP connection with mobile provider (JSMPP). Now I want give SMPP connection to another person over SMPP. (Mobile provider doesn't allow give direct SMPP connection to another person) How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you correctly; you want to setup your own SMPP infrastructure that basically authenticates a user and forwards all requests to another SMPP provider.

*You have two options:*

1. Implement a very basic ESME using an SMPP API like jsmpp, that sits in between user requests and your provider. Authenticate users and forward their requests.
2. Utilize a proxy that can listen in and monitor SMPP type connections at the tcp level. Observe the transport data for authentication details, and modify them as appropriate, before    forwarding to your provider. This is really programme-agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

The best choice I think is to implement a simple gateway on top of jsmpp and use it for all internal systems. If that another person is your friend you can create it without any authentication.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly, you have an ESME that uses a mobile provider's(SMSC) credentials to send  SMSes to mobile users and know you want to use those credentials for another ESME (of friend). The SMSC will not allow your friend's ESME because the credentials are specific for yours ESME. Your friend will have to get his own credential from the mobile provider (SMSC).